# Include only specific subfolders in git

Tags: git, gitignore

I've a folder structure as shown below

```
--app
----design
------fold1
------fold2
------MyDesign
--------(my files)
----code
------fold3
------fold4
------MyCode
--------(my files)
----(some folders i dont care about)
----(some files i dont care about)
```

I've created a git repo @ `app/` folder. How will i ignore all the files and folders other than `app/design/MyDesign` and `app/code/MyCode`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative gitignore patterns:

```
$ cat app/.gitignore
*
!./app/design/MyDesign
!./app/code/MyCode
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. i've tried this, but it doesn't work. it ignores all the files and folders (including those i need)

Comment: @shahalpk: I changed the pattern to a relative path. Please try again.